# How to buy a game for a kid account in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: 7.x, games, parental-control, family-safety

Recently I retired my old Windows Phone 7 handset and my 9 years old has inherited it (with no SIM card, just to play games). Until now he has just played free games but now I want to buy a paid game for him, but I can't figure out how to do it.

He has his own Microsoft account which is associated to my account as "family".  I have entered my credit card details in his account (I plan to remove them immediately after the game is purchased) and I have configured his privacy setting in xbox.com so that he is allowed to download paid games. But when I try to download the game in his phone, a message appears saying *"Can't complete the request due to parental control in your account".*

I'm sure that I am missing any other needed configuration step but I can't figure out which one. What else do I need to do so that my son can download the game to his phone? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's his age. He cannot make purchases. The only way to get around it is to reset the phone and use a new account that is aged 13 or over.